# Export Google bookmarks into an excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-bookmarks

I have a bookmark folder where I have bookmarked various professor's profiles. There are some 40 bookmarked links. I wanted to know if there is a way I can export the bookmark in an excel sheet with the following columns:

1. bookmark name
2. bookmark link

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only 40 I'd just export them to a .csv (comma-separated values) and (I'm lazy) use regex to mark all the links, cut and paste them all into a single column (I'd choose column B). The remaining list can then simply be marked using the remaining , as separators and pasted into Column A (giving you the right name for the right link).

Does that make sense?

Also if you're not familiar with Regex you could of course just do the same thing iteratively.